# How to make this command safe, and work for quoted strings

Tags: perl, bash, ubuntu, command

I found (and adapted a bit) a command to edit a list of files using regex (and perl). I put it into a script file called `cred`, so I can do `cred . england England` to replace all occurrences of `england` with `England` in all files in the current directory.

```
find $1 -type f -exec perl -e 's/'$2'/'$3'/g' -p -i {} \;
```

It is wicked powerful, and already useful - but dangerous, and flawed. I would like it to...

1. preview changes (or at least files operated on) first, asking confirmation
2. work with longer strings than a single word. I tried `cred . england 'the United Kingdom'` but it fails

I would also be interested in other (short and memorable, universally installed/installable on osx and ubuntu) commands to achieve the same thing.

EDIT:

This is what I have so far - open to improvements...

```
# highlight the spots that will be modified (not specifying the file)
find $1 -type f -exec grep -E "$2" --color {} \;
# get confirmation
read -p "Are you sure? " -n 1 -r
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
  # make changes, and highlight the spots that were changed
  find $1 -type f -exec perl -e "s/$2/$3/g" -p -i {} \;
  echo ""
  find $1 -type f -exec grep -E "$3" --color {} \;
else
  echo ""
  echo "Aborted!!"
fi
```

Comment: Rather than writing up an increasingly complicated shell script which calls out to Perl, consider writing it all in Perl using File::Find.  It will then be A) debuggable B) easier to do more complicated substitutions C) avoid shell quoting issues and D) easier to do the verification and change *per file* rather than have the user verify everything and then change everything.

Comment: I just realized that your program highlights using `grep -E` but does the search and replace using Perl.  This might cause the patterns to be interpreted differently.  If your grep supports it, use `grep -P` to interpret patterns using [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work on strings with spaces, write your command like:

```
perl -e "s/$2/$3/g"
```

If you use double quotes, variables will be expanded inside the quotes.

To do something like previewing changes and asking for confirmation you will need a much more complex script.  One very easy thing to do would be to just run `find $1 -type f` first to get a listing of all the files, and then use the `read` command to get some input and decide if you should continue.

Comment: I am kind of surprised the double quotes works, as I would expect it to be understood as captures in regex, rather than command line arguments of the outer script - but it does work. Thanks!

Comment: The shell expands the variables before passing the regex on to perl.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure Perl version using File::Find.  It is quite a bit longer, but easier to debug and do more complicated things with.  And it works per file which allows for an easier time doing the verification.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie;
use File::Find;
use File::Temp;

my($Search, $Replace, $Dir) = @ARGV;

# Useful for testing
run($Dir);

sub run {
    my $dir = shift;
    find \&replace_with_verify, $dir;
}

sub replace_with_verify {
    my $file = $_;
    return unless -f $file;

    print "File: $file\n";

    if( verify($file, $Search) ) {
        replace($file, $Search, $Replace);
        print "\nReplaced: $file\n";
        highlight($file, $Replace);
    }
    else {
        print "Ignoring $file\n";
    }

    print "\n";
}

sub verify {
    my($file, $search) = @_;

    highlight($file, $search);

    print "Are you sure? [Yn] ";
    my $answer = <STDIN>;

    # default to yes
    return 0 if $answer =~ /^n/i;
    return 1;
}

sub replace {
    my($file, $search, $replace) = @_;

    open my $in, "<", $file;
    my $out = File::Temp->new;

    while(my $line = <$in>) {
        $line =~ s{$search}{$replace}g;
        print $out $line;
    }

    close $in;
    close $out;

    return rename $out->filename, $file;
}

sub highlight {
    my($file, $pattern) = @_;

    # Use PCRE grep.  Should probably just do it in Perl to ensure accuracy.
    system "grep", "-P", "--color", $pattern, $file;    # Should probably use a pager
}
```